# Java OpenCSV Writing Result Set - End of Line / Row

Tags: java, csv, opencsv

I'm trying to export a SQL resultset to a comma delimited csv file using opencsv library. However when I pass the result set to the writeAll function, all works well except for the file that it generates does not separates the rows with a new line and creates a nearly un readable file when opened in notepad. Albeit the file that is created is valid and delimits well when imported into excel. However, I need the file this code generates to be readable when opened with a simple text editor. Any suggestions?

My CSV file handle looks like this:

```
CSVWriter wt = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("file"), ',',
    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, "\n");
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use the [System Properties: line separator](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/environment/sysprop.html) instead of "\n" (on Windows, ["\r\n"](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newline) is end of line),

```
CSVWriter wt = new CSVWriter(new FileWriter("file"), ',', 
    CSVWriter.NO_QUOTE_CHARACTER, 
    CSVWriter.NO_ESCAPE_CHARACTER, 
    System.getProperty("line.separator"));
```

From the System Properties link above,

> "**line.seperator**"
>   Sequence used by operating system to separate lines in text files

Comment: Alternatively, you could always use [Notepad++](http://notepad-plus-plus.org/) (free as in speech and beer).